# How to dynamically create a card/button object on ASP.net webpage based on entries in the backend database?

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MSSQL Server database table with 10 employees' names and their titles. I want to create an ASP .NET webform with each one of those employees displayed as a "card" object on the front end. I am able to do it for a static number of records using the asp button object and using the css class to make it look like a card visually. However, the data in the table changes when there are new additions or deletes. How can the creation of a new card be dynamic/automated when a new employee is added to the database table?

I have attached a screenshot with an example of employee ids displayed on their cards. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Just layout one bit of markup for one card. Get it all nice looking.

Then wrap the markup inside of a repeater (so it repeats).

So, say this markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>                   
        <div style="border-style:solid;color:black;width:320px;height:450px;float:left;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px">
            <div style="text-align:center;padding:2px 10px 2px 10px">
                <h3><%# Eval("Fighter") %></h3>
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" 
                    ImageUrl = '<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' Width="170" />
                <h4>Engine</h4>
                <asp:Label ID="EngineLabel2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Engine") %>' />
                <h4>Description</h4>
                <asp:Label ID="DescLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

So, for each row - we fill controls with a "eval" expression as per above.

So, now our code to load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable rstData;
        rstData = MyRst("select * from Fighters");

        Repeater1.DataSource = rstData;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}


public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
{
    DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Deafult.Settings.TEST4))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader);
            rstData.TableName = strSQL;
        }
    }
    return rstData;
}
```

And now we get this output:

[image]

And if I open up the browser to a larger view, then I get this:

[image]

so, since each div is just floated left, then they stack up along side each other.

When you run out of room, then they go to the next line.

You can also use a datalist, as it will let you specify the repeating number of columns, but a simple repeater should work just fine.

So, you have a "thing" of markup, and you want to repeat it?

Then use a repeater as per above. How a ListView, datalist, GridView etc. work? They all can have a data source that you feed it, and it will create a new instance for each record from the data you feed it.

Comment: Hi Albert. Thank you very much for your help with this. However, I am unable to view the images attached when I click the highlighted text. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You have to post your code used for the click event for that text box when clicked on. However some code for some click event for some text box is a VERY different question then that of how to display repeating data in a card view layout as per your question. If some click code for some text box or label does not work then start a new question and include your markup and include the click code on text that's not working.

Comment: It is possible I did not grasp what you mean by click on image attached?? Do you mean the images in this post? or do you mean your own sample and images and code? The images in this post are just that  --- a image. You can click on the images in this post - they will not do much - (all they will do is display again in your browser).

Comment: <asp:Image didn't work for me I had to use <img tag
.

Success:
<img alt="" width="100" src='https://yourserver.net/meterportal/images/<%#Eval("defaultWebInfoPageImage")%>' />

Comment: It will depend on how you saved/stored the path in the database. I stored the path name as a SERVER side path name. So, "~/" is NOT allowed unless you use a server side expression and code.  The code as posted does in fact work as the screen caps show.